# How to declare state_attrs in Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, reporting, state

I had a requirement to track run history of a set of cookbooks.

Chef reporting provides a good base, it can capture the cookbook run history as well as resources updated. But I still need to capture the initial state and final state of the resource updated.

For some recipes, it uses some default resource, like file, then in the

> Chef Reporting -> Run History -> Details -> Parameters

it can show the initial and final state, for example they are checksum, mode, group, owner attributes for file. It is quite good.

But for other recipes, it uses a new resource developed by myself, there is no initial and final state. As specified in [chef reporting document](http://docs.chef.io/reporting.html#state-attrs-method), the "**state_attrs**" is used to define attributes to be reported to chef reporting server.

The question is that I did a quick test, to declare 2 attributes using state_attrs, but they still do not show in the run history initial and final state...

Could you please advise me how to add state_attrs?

Or if there are other ways to track initial and final state of changed resource, they are also highly appreciated! I tried to use the report handler, but in report handler, I can not get the initial state, there is a 'before' field, but it is empty...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is figured out, there are 3 steps to achieve the goal:

1. declare state_attrs in resource
2. there are new_resource and current_resource object, it requires
   explicitly initialize current_resource by adding a method in the
   resource provider, for example:

> ```
>   def load_current_resource
>    @current_resource = Chef::Resource::MyResource.new(@new_resource.name)
>   end
> ```

3. assign value to current_resource in where it is updated. for
   example:

> ```
> @current_resource.maxage(smaxdays.to_s)
> ```

It is an example to check password max age for users. It will set the smaxdays, which is retrieved from shadow file, to current_resource.

Then the maxage will be sent to chef reporting, the data will be like:

```
res_initial_state: {"maxage":"7777"}   
res_final_state:  {"maxage":"90"}
```

That is exactly the initial and final state I want to capture.